# several charts in single webview

Tags: android, webview, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to put 3 different Google charts on a single web-page but am unable to get it, i am only able to get single chart, but when i try to get many at once i got stuck.

I would be very thankful for useful suggestions.
thanks!!

I am refering [This](http://kurtchen.com/blog/2010/03/18/use-android-webview-and-google-chart-api-to-display-data/#comment-1819), to work with putting multiple charts in single webview.

my actual code looks like this..
But is only to display single chart.

```
public void getMaps()
{   
    String url =  "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bhg&chd=t:25,45&chs=300x100&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|iOS|android";
    WebView mCharView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.char_view);
    mCharView.loadUrl(url);     
}
```

Comment: the tutorial you reference provides the code for viewing multiple charts at once. Did you try that code?

Comment: private String getData() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<img src=\"<a href="http://0.chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=250x150&chd=s:Monkeys&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt|1,0000ff,10,1,lt\" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://0.chart.apis.google.com']);">http://0.chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=250x150&chd=s:Monkeys&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt|1,0000ff,10,1,lt\</a>"/><br>");

    return sb.toString();
    }

yes, but this is giving error 
“Syntax error, insert “;” to complete Statement” 
How to handle this?

Comment: I see. It looks like there is an error in the sample they give. You need to escape each of the `"` characters in the string, which you do by adding a `\` right before it. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: now i had try this, but this time also giving error